# json decode for telegram bot

Tags: php, json, telegram-bot

I have this file `json` received from asking the photo profile picture in php in a telegram bot and I want to save only some few information about it.
This is the code:

```
{
"ok": true,
"result": {
    "total_count": 16,
    "photos": [
        [
            {
                "file_id": "2342423423252",
                "file_size": 13038,
                "width": 160,
                "height": 160
            },
            {
                "file_id": "2342423423252",
                "file_size": 13038,
                "width": 160,
                "height": 160
            },
            {
                "file_id": "2342423423252",
                "file_size": 13038,
                "width": 160,
                "height": 160
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "file_id": "2342423423252",
                "file_size": 13038,
                "width": 160,
                "height": 160
            },
            {
                "file_id": "2342423423252",
                "file_size": 13038,
                "width": 160,
                "height": 160
            },
            {
                "file_id": "2342423423252",
                "file_size": 13038,
                "width": 160,
                "height": 160
            }
        ],
          ...
```

I have to save only the `file_id`, but I don't know how to do it.

Not  necessarily all the file_id, just once!
Sorry for my bad english.. 
Someone can help me?

Comment: use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert the json string to an array of objects (or arrays), then loop over the photos to get the value(s) you need.

Comment: Yes, i tryed ti do it.. But I can't find the correct syntax for the multiple object... I think this is an array of "result" that have inside a array of "photos" that have an array of "??" That inside there is my "file_ID"? I'm very confused... D:

Comment: Take it one step at a time, if you're not into xdebug yet you can just `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($value);die();` in your loop to see what data you have. Then it should be easy to work your way into the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$x = json_decode($yourJSON, true);
$id = $x["result"]["photos"][0][0]["file_id"]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! "[0][0]" this is my problem! I forgot them! thanks!